# SQL Procedure with LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-like

I am trying to learn more about procedures in SQL, and so i am trying to do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCarInformation
(@ModelName Varchar(256))
AS
Begin
SELECT Car.LicensePlate, CarBrand.ManufacturerName, CarModel.ModelName, CarSpecs.ModelYear, CarSpecs.Doors, CarSpecs.Seats, CarSpecs.ModelYear
FROM Car
INNER JOIN CarModel ON Car.ModelID = CarModel.ID
INNER JOIN CarBrand ON CarModel.ManufacturerID = CarBrand.ID
INNER JOIN CarSpecs ON CarModel.CarSpecsID = CarSpecs.ID
WHERE CarModel.ModelName LIKE '%@ModelName%'
END
```

But it doesn't seem to work, on the LIKE part of it. 
It wont search correctly. 
Is it because i am using it incorrectly ?
Or can't i add % with the @ModelName ? and single quotes ?

Comment: @MatiasThayer i have no idea what tensorflow is ?

Comment: First thing to learn : **define** what **concrete RDBMS** you're using. "SQL" is not precise enough - almost all RDBMS use SQL as their query language, but the procedural code stuff is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a relevant tag (like `db2`,  `oracle`, `mysql`, `sql-server` etc.) to your question

Comment: @marc_s, sorry i didn't know it was different

Comment: `LIKE '%'+@ModelName+'%'`

Comment: @Serg That worked !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
LIKE '%'+@ModelName+'%'
```

It's the way MSSQL use to CONCAT string .  You can use CONCAT() too.

Please remember to use LIKE '%xxx%' with caution.  It can have really bad effects on performances.

Comment: The LIKE is only for testing small scripts, but thanks, it was exactly what i was looking for.